# How to update several vertex properties on Gremlin?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I want to add several properties on a vertex. I could do:

```
g.v(1).firstname='Marko'
g.v(1).lastname='Rodriguez'
```

But how to add these properties with the following hash {firstname:'Marko', lastname:'Rodriguez'} in a single query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can construct a SideEffect pipe that would work. In the simple case, do this:

```
g.v(1)._().sideEffect{it.firstname='Marko'; it.lastname='Rodriguez'}
```

Alternatively, if you need to work on just one node and have the map you can use the `each` method of a map:

```
m = [firstname:'Marko', lastname:'Rodriguez']
m.each{g.v(1).setProperty(it.key, it.value)}
```

Or you could do this inside of a pipe where you have a hash with values you wish to set. Once again, we'll use the sideEffect pipe. Because there is a closure inside of a closure we need to alias the value of `it` from the first closure to something else, in this case `tn`, short for "this node", so it is accessible in the second closure.:

```
g = new TinkerGraph()
g.addVertex()
g.addVertex()
m = ['0': [firstname: 'Marko', lastname: 'Rodriguez'], '1': [firstname: 'William', lastname: 'Clinton']]
g.V.sideEffect{tn = it; m[tn.id].each{tn.setProperty(it.key, it.value)}}
```

This will yield the following:

```
gremlin> g.v(0).map
==>lastname=Rodriguez
==>firstname=Marko
gremlin> g.v(1).map
==>lastname=Clinton
==>firstname=William
```

One potential gotcha with this method is that you need to remember that vertex id's are strings, not integers, so make sure to quote them appropriately.

Comment: Thank you Pridkett, I will test this as soon as possible. But I thought there would be an easier solution.